# awk in loop 'miraculously' changes variable value in -v option

Tags: awk, sh

I am struggling with awk. 
I use awk inside a loop of a shell script and pass the same variable with the same value with the -v option.  However, in the second passage of the loop the variable changes its value from "2" to "6" ???  What am I doing wrong

I tried to change the syntax of the print expression, but anyway, the first of the three awk lines is pretty minimal :-/

```
#!/bin/sh
dows="1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5 0%2C6"
day=2
count=2
echo $dows
num=1
while [ "$num" -le $count ]
do
    thisdow=$(echo $dows | awk -v var="$num" '{print $var}')
    echo "this days of week are: $thisdow"
    echo "this day is $day"
    echo "control day"
    echo $(echo $thisdow | awk -v var="$day" 'BEGIN { FS = "%2C" }; {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){print $var}}')
    echo "control days of week"
    echo $(echo $thisdow | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "%2C" }; {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){print $i}}')
    echo "difference"
    echo $(echo $thisdow | awk -v var="$day" 'BEGIN { FS = "%2C" }; {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){print ($i - $var + 7) % 7}}')
    num=$(expr $num + 1)
done
```

Sorry if the code snipplet is a bit long, but I really am clueless.  Maybe some sort of memory leak, but I do not know where to narrow it down further....
the first awk line ouputs `2 2 2 2 2 2` for the first time, what I expect, and `6 6` the second time, which leaves me puzzled.  Here is the full output

```
1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5 0%2C6
this days of week are: 1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5
this day is 2
control day
2 2 2 2 2
control days of week
1 2 3 4 5
difference
6 0 1 2 3
this days of week are: 0%2C6
this day is 2
control day
6 6  <---- this is what drives me insane...
control days of week
0 6
difference
1 0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: To use `var` in your program, just say `var`, not `$var` (unless `var` is supposed to contain a field number and you want the value of the field)

Answer (score 1):

ok, I knew it would be something silly.
The '$' must be omitted, otherwise $var is interpreted as the second field, which happens to work coincidentally in the first pass through the loop
The correct awk line in the code should be (only the first one)

```
echo $(echo $thisdow | awk -v var="$day" 'BEGIN { FS = "%2C" }; {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){print var}}')
```